# Cómo limpiar un array de valores duplicados PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de logs con PHP/MySQL/SQL, y para que funcione de forma adecuada tengo que mejorar ciertas cosas del código:

```
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
   
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('$value[0]')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    var_dump($resultado);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."fue insertado correctamente. <br>";

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Ha habido errores al insertar los artículos nuevos en la tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }

        
}
```

Aquí actualmente me da errores en la inserción (aunque lo hace de forma correcta) porque hay veces que me intenta introducir `ean` repetidos (PK, 13 dígitos, le he puesto `UNIQUE` en MySQL también). Entiendo que tengo que hacer algo para limpiar $EANsNoCoinciden, pero la pregunta es... ¿Cómo lo limpio para evitar que haya eans repetidos? Gracias, saludos.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

Estoy intentando limpiar actualmente con este código:

```
$EANsNoCoincidenLimpio=array_values(array_unique($EANsNoCoinciden));
var_dump($EANsNoCoincidenLimpio);
```

Sin embargo, `var_dump($EANsNoCoincidenLimpio)` sólo me devuelve `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "SMS46MW19E" } } bool(true)`  y sólo me inserta eso, por tanto. ¿Necesitaría un foreach también aquí? Por la documentación que he visto en Internet, tanto `array_values` como `array_unique` te lo limpian todo sin tener que recorrer nada, pero igual lo he entendido mal. Gracias.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:

Estoy probando con `ON DUPLICATE KEY` pero no acabo de entender la sintaxis a la hora de ejecutarlo (me hago un lío con los valores del final). He probado con:

```
INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('1234567890123') ON DUPLICATE KEY '1234567890123'='1234567890123');

INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('1234567890123') ON DUPLICATE KEY `ean`='1234567890123');

INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('1234567890123') ON DUPLICATE KEY `ean`=`ean`);
```

Pero da errores por todos lados (esto en MYSQL). No sé bien cómo puedo hacerlo. Gracias.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 3:

Esto es lo que hay al hacer un `var_dump()` de `$EANsNoCoinciden`:

```
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "0649528776389"
  }
```

Comment: ¿Tienes cargados en alguna variable TODOS los EAN existentes? Si no, es probable que cargar un listado en memoria con todos los EAN ya existentes y procesar el listado de los que quieras insertar no es escalable (con el tiempo irá tardando más e incluso podría llegar a agotar la memoria). Que falle una inserción no tiene por qué ser necesariamente malo.

Comment: (Me quedé sin espacio en el comentario anterior). También podrías hacer una inserción y que actualice el registro en caso de que éste exista ([`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) o bien un [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)). Todo depende de cómo funcione tu aplicación y tengas organizados tus datos en la base de datos. Recuerda que dependiendo del caso (por ejemplo en importaciones) una clave duplicada no debería ser necesariamente un error, simplemente hay que decidir qué hacer en ese caso.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar. Todos los Ean están en $EANsNoCoinciden. Lo del INSERT ON DUPLICATE O REPLACE teniendo el Ean en MySQL como UNIQUE no sé si es mejor opción que la que estoy intentando con código PHP. Espero tu feedback, gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo sería ``` $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('$value[0]')";``` con el ```INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE```? ¿Sería algo así como ```INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ($value[0]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ean``=$value[0]```? Dónde no sé como estructurarlo es al poner la condición = tras el ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, al tener que mezclar SQL y PHP. Gracias.

Comment: Tengo mas dudas que respuestas la verdad.. que hay dentro de `EANsNoCoinciden` ? es una lista de eans? hay objetos dentro? es una lista de listas? ya que haces values[0]

Comment: He actualizado con un ejemplo del ```var_dump()``` de ```EANsNoCoinciden```.

Comment: Disculpa mi ausencia (trabajo). ¿Me estás diciendo que el único campo que hay en la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` es `ean`? En ese caso sería más sencillo hacer un [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), porque poner el mismo valor en un único campo que sabemos que contiene precisamente el valor que va a ser guardado, es inútil y tiempo perdido. @nax, `$EANsNoCoinciden` no nos sirve para hacer un cribado previo porque ahí están los EAN que van a insertar, no TODOS los que hay en la tabla.

Comment: A ver, hay más campos en ```articulos_nuevos_definitiva``` pero con este script sólo quiero insertar ```ean```. Pruebo con ```INSERT IGNORE``` y te digo :)

Comment: Efectivamente. La solución ha sido el ```INSERT IGNORE```. Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con [array unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique)?

```php
$array = array(1, 2, 2, 3); // Arrau con valores 1 2 2 3
$array = array_unique($array); // Ahora el array es 1 2 3
```

Comment: Estoy probando con array_values(array_unique($array)). Aquí tienes la explicación: http://lineadecodigo.com/php/eliminar-elementos-duplicados-de-un-array-en-php/.

Comment: Otra manera, si no quieres usar ese método, es que uses una colección indexada para no tener que recurrir a un bucle dentro de otro y optimizar las iteraciones si finalmente recurres a un forach para llenar el array

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con colección indexada?

Comment: Debido a la escalabilidad del problema, y que se trata de busquedas que van a ser crecientes, sería bueno que usaras tablas de hash para agilizar la busqueda conjuntamente con el método array_unique. De esta manera en vez de hacer busquedas en tiempo lineal pordrás hacer búsqueda en tiempo constante, y de esta manera inicializarás un diccionario que se llene a medida que iteras en el array y va llenando de concurrencias con su posición del mismo para que cuando tengas que buscar una concurrencia esta sea atacada. Una sola iteración para atacar las concurrencias.

Answer (score 1):

No te funciona `array_unique(array_values())` porque tu arreglo debería ser asociativo:

```
[
    'Elemento1' => 'Valor1',
    'Elemento2' => 'Valor2',
    'ElementoX' => 'ValorX'
]
```

Sin embargo, al parecer, tienes un arreglo donde cada elemento es otro arreglo con un solo elemento:

```
[
    [0 => 'Valor1'], // Es lo mismo que ['Valor1'] (sin índice)
    [0 => 'Valor2'],
    [0 => 'ValorX']
]
```

Podrías usar [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) para recorrer el arreglo y "normalizarlo", pero no le veo sentido a ejecutar otro ciclo; revisa el comentario al final de la respuesta.

Sin ver cómo armas los datos, lo que puedes hacer es crear una lista de elementos que ya insertaste, verificar cada uno e insertar si aún no está en la lista u omitir si ya está:

```
$insertados = [];
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
    // Verificar si ya se insertó
    if(in_array($value[0], $insertados) {
        // Ya se insertó... omitir
        continue;
    }
    // Agregar a lista
    $insertados[] = $value[0];
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('$value[0]')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    var_dump($resultado);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."fue insertado correctamente. <br>";

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Ha habido errores al insertar los artículos nuevos en la tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }
}
```

La función [in_array(elemento, arreglo)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) devuelve verdadero si el elemento existe en el arreglo o falso si no existe.

Esta respuesta es "un poco más óptima" que la tuya porque evitas hacer consultas a la base de datos cuando no es necesario; sin embargo, todavía se puede mejorar si desde la consulta donde obtienes los valores filtras para obtener elementos únicos y, de no ser posible, realizar el filtrado al armar el arreglo `$EANsNoCoinciden`.

Answer (score 0):

La solución más simple y eficiente ha sido ésta:

```
 $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('$value[0]')";
```

Con el `INSERT IGNORE INTO` si te encuentra un valor duplicado no te lo meterá, y listo.

Comment: "Solución más simple", probablemente sí, "eficiente"... lo dudo mucho, porque estarás generando consultas a la base de datos que no son necesarias.